# Git Bash: "fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: windows, git, windows-vista, clone

I am using a Windows Vista machine with msysgit installed and attempting to clone a remote git repository using Git Bash, but I get the error "fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly".  I am able to SSH my company's server and get a listing of repositories, and the server admin has granted me access to the ones I'm trying to clone.  The server admin reports that I am not connecting to the server when I run "git clone ".  Also, I am not asked for the password on my private key.  I have successfully set up projects from the same repository on the same machine before.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the full command you are issuing (with private names substituted if necessary).

Comment: from your git bash prompt type: 'ssh <server>'  and see what happens.  if its setup right, you should just get an access report.  if it asks for a pw, something isnt setup right.

Comment: @kanaka git clone git@git.<company_name>.com:<project_name>.git; @Jon already did it, it connects via SSH and I can see the listing of the remote repositories using "show-repos" or something like that.  Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth explicitly adding the ssh protocol specifier:

```
git clone ssh://git@git.somewhere.com/path/to/project
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the case in when you specify the repository name. The URLs are case sensitive.